# Problemas al integrar plugins de bootstrap y jquery en laravel

Tags: jquery, bootstrap

Estoy intentando utilizar el plugin timepicker en mi pagina y no muestra nada cuando lo llamo dentro de un input, también he intentado con otros como select2, colorpicker y tampoco funcionan, mis archivos css y js son locales y no se si tengo que hacer algo mas a parte de importarlos, o que es lo que estoy haciendo mal.

Este es mi blade que se llama layout:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!--Estilos propios-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/estilos.css')}}">
    <!--font google-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--font icons-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!--Time Picker-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('timepicker/bootstrap-timepicker.min.css')}}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('timepicker/bootstrap-timepicker.css')}}"/>


    <!-- Estilos para el select multiple-->    
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" 

    href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.min.css"/> -->
      </head>
      <body>
        @yield('content');
        <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
        <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrit y="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-7aThvCh9TypR7fIc2HV4O/nFMVCBwyIUKL8XCtKE+8xgCgl/PQGuFsvShjr74PBp" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!--Time Picker-->
    <script src="{{asset('timepicker/bootstrap-timepicker.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('timepicker/bootstrap-timepicker.js')}}"></script>
    <!-- <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.min.js"></script> -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Y aqui es el otro blade donde quiero utilizar el timepicker

```
    @extends('tiempo.layout')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="inputHora">Hora</label>
        <i class="far fa-clock"></i><input type="text" class="form-control timepicker" name="time"/>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
  $('.timepicker').timepicker();
</script>
@endsection
```

Comment: Aparentemente todo está bien, comprueba que las rutas de la lirería esten bien en la consola.

Comment: ¿Aparece el error 404 al cargar dicho assets en DevTools?

Comment: ¿Porqué estás usando dos veces los archivos `bootstrap.min.js`? Me refiero a diferentes versiones: 4.2.1 y 4.3.0

Comment: No, no hay el error 404, carga normal la pagina solo que no esta cargando el timepicker, se ve como un input normal donde hasta me permite escribir

Comment: Lo mismo haces con jQuery, aunque es la misma versión, lo estás llamando dos veces en el mismo archivo

Comment: Era por un select multiple que estaba manejando. Pero igual probé al eliminar el de la versión 4.2.1 y aún así no funciona el timepicker

Comment: fijate que estas repitiendo tus js incluidos... jquery3.3.1 el poperjs y bootstrapjs